# Isomorphism of a Polynomial Linear Transformation

Tags: vector-space-isomorphism

Show that $T: \mathcal{P}_n \to \mathcal{P}_n$ defined by $T(p(x))=p(x+ 2
)$ is bijective by showing that it is injective and surjective by definition (injective: $\vec u \neq \vec v \implies T(\vec u) \neq T(\vec v)$, surjective: $range(T) = \mathcal{P}_n$).

Comment: Your implication is going the wrong way. Injective means $T(u) = T(v) \Rightarrow u=v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that $T$ is one-to-one and onto.

For one-to-oneness:

Let $$T(P_1(x))=T(P_2(x))$$

$$P_1(x+2)= P_2(x+2)$$ be true for all $x$

Thus it is also true for $x-2$ that is $$P_1(x-2+2)= P_2(x-2+2)$$ That is  $$P_1(x) = P_2(x)$$

For onto-ness note that $$T(P(x-2)) = P(x-2+2)=P(x)$$ Thus for any  P(x) there is  a preimage namely   $P(x-2)$

Answer (score 0):

Notation can trip you up here.

Better to write
$(Tp)(x) = p(x+2)$. It just shifts the graph of $p$ to the left.

The antidote is to shift to the right by the same amount:
$(Sp)(x) = p(x-2)$.

Check $(S(Tp))(x) = (Tp)(x-2) = p((x-2)+2 = p$, and similarly $(T(Sp))(x) = p$.

Hence $S$ is the inverse, it follows that $T$ is bijective.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to say that I must use the definition of bijectivity (updated the post).

Comment: You can use the above to prove that $T$ is injective & surjective.